# tkz diagrams causing vbox badness

Tags: environments, tkz-euclide

How do I stop the vbox badness in the following, it only stops if I make my diagrams scale=0.3cm and I don't want them that small, I know it doesn't show on the WME but in the full document this is the only diagram that affects it.

```
    \documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, openright,fleqn, leqno, draft, ]{book}

    \usepackage{tkz-euclide}            %Tkz-Euclide diagrams
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,cancel}                  %Math packages

    %Diagram environment
    \newenvironment{diagram}
    {%
    \par\addvspace{0pt}%
    \centering
    \stepcounter{CountDiag}
    \tkzSetUpCompass[lenth=1cm]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    }{%
    \end{tikzpicture}\par
    \vspace{-20pt}
    Diagram~\theCountDiag\par
    \addvspace{0pt}
    }
%    \newcounter{CountDiag}\counterwithin*{CountDiag}.   {section}%
    \newcounter{CountDiag}\counterwithin*{CountDiag}{section}%

    \newcommand{\Tri}[8]{%%
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){#1}%
    \tkzDefPoint({#2,#3}){#4}%
    \tkzDefPoint({#5,#6}){#7}%
    \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=#8](#1,#4,#7)%
    \tkzLabelPoint[left](#1){$#1$}% 
    \tkzLabelPoint[below](#4){$#4$}%
    \tkzLabelPoint[above](#7){$#7$}%
    \tkzDrawPoints(#1,#4,#7)%
    }

    \begin{document}

    \begin{diagram}[scale=0.7]
    \Tri{B}{3}{0}{C}{1.5}{3}{A}{none}
        \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=2](A,B)          \tkzGetPoint{E}
        \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=2](A,C)          \tkzGetPoint{D}
        \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=1.5](A,B)            \tkzGetPoint{F}
        \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=1.5](A,C)            \tkzGetPoint{G} 
         \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
         \tkzDrawSegment(A,E)
         \tkzDrawSegment(A,D)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left](E)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right](D)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left](F)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right](G)
        \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,C)
        \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,B)
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](A,C,B)
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](C,B,A)
        \tkzDrawPoints[fill=gray](A,B,C,D,E,F,G)
         \tkzDrawSegment[dashed](C,F)
     \end{tikzpicture}
    \hspace{0.3cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
       \Tri{B}{3}{0}{C}{1.5}{3}{A}{none}
       \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=2](A,B)           \tkzGetPoint{E}
    \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=2](A,C)      \tkzGetPoint{D}
        \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=1.5](A,B)            \tkzGetPoint{F}
        \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=1.5](A,C)            \tkzGetPoint{G} 
        \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
        \tkzDrawSegment(A,E)
        \tkzDrawSegment(A,D)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left](E)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right](D)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left](F)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right](G)       
        \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,C)
        \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,B)
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](A,C,B)
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](C,B,A)
        \tkzDrawSegment[dashed](B,G)
        \tkzDrawPoints[fill=gray](A,B,C,D,E,F,G)
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \hspace{0.3cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
       \Tri{B}{3}{0}{C}{1.5}{3}{A}{none}
          \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=2](A,B)            \tkzGetPoint{E}
        \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=2](A,C)          \tkzGetPoint{D}
        \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=1.5](A,B)            \tkzGetPoint{F}
        \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=1.5](A,C)            \tkzGetPoint{G} 
        \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
        \tkzDrawSegment(A,E)
        \tkzDrawSegment(A,D)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left](E)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right](D)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left](F)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right](G)       
        \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,C)
        \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,B)
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](A,C,B)
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](C,B,A)
        \tkzDrawSegment[dashed](B,G)
          \tkzDrawSegment[dashed](C,F)
        \tkzDrawPoints[fill=gray](A,B,C,D,E,F,G)
    \end{diagram}
    \end{document}
```

sorry for the long code but its mainly just diagram stuff.

Screenshot:

[image: result]

Comment: It does not compile.

Comment: ! LaTeX Error: No counter '.' defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.20 ...nter{CountDiag}\counterwithin*{CountDiag}.
                                                     {section}%
?

Comment: FYI: With the correction I edited it will compile.

Comment: As an aside, your `[scale=0.7]`  should be `[scale=0.7,transorm shape]` ,  see https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#autosec-3197

Comment: 1) I've compiled your code with lualatex and I don't have any vbox problems. 2) `scale=.7` it's a bad idea. You have three fixed points, it is preferable to modify them and avoid scaling. TeX does the calculations, and this is detrimental to compilation speed and accuracy.

Comment: @MS-SPO Why add `transform shape`? By doing so you modify the fonts ...

Comment: Sometimes it's useful: "17.7 Transformations // It is possible to transform nodes, but, by default, transformations do not apply to nodes. The reason is that you usually do not want your text to be scaled or rotated even if the main graphic is transformed. Scaling text is evil, rotating slightly less so. " Over and out.

Comment: The error is gone but (as you comment in the question) the code shown is not an example of the problem you ask about so it does not help anyone answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code shown does not have any underful vbox, although it may take part in page breaking producing a page that is underful. (You could have simplified the example replacing all the tikz by `\rule{5pt}{4cm}` as all that matters is the vertical size of the diagram.)

An example of your problem is

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, openright,fleqn, leqno, draft, ]{book}

    \usepackage{tkz-euclide}            %Tkz-Euclide diagrams
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,cancel}                  %Math packages

    %Diagram environment
    \newenvironment{diagram}
    {%
    \par\addvspace{0pt}%
    \centering
    \stepcounter{CountDiag}
    \tkzSetUpCompass[lenth=1cm]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    }{%
    \end{tikzpicture}\par
    \vspace{-20pt}
    Diagram~\theCountDiag\par
    \addvspace{0pt}
    }
%    \newcounter{CountDiag}\counterwithin*{CountDiag}.   {section}%
    \newcounter{CountDiag}\counterwithin*{CountDiag}{section}%

    \newcommand{\Tri}[8]{%%
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){#1}%
    \tkzDefPoint({#2,#3}){#4}%
    \tkzDefPoint({#5,#6}){#7}%
    \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=#8](#1,#4,#7)%
    \tkzLabelPoint[left](#1){$#1$}% 
    \tkzLabelPoint[below](#4){$#4$}%
    \tkzLabelPoint[above](#7){$#7$}%
    \tkzDrawPoints(#1,#4,#7)%
    }

    \begin{document}

    \begin{diagram}[scale=0.7]
    \Tri{B}{3}{0}{C}{1.5}{3}{A}{none}
        \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=2](A,B)          \tkzGetPoint{E}
        \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=2](A,C)          \tkzGetPoint{D}
        \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=1.5](A,B)            \tkzGetPoint{F}
        \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=1.5](A,C)            \tkzGetPoint{G} 
         \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
         \tkzDrawSegment(A,E)
         \tkzDrawSegment(A,D)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left](E)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right](D)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left](F)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right](G)
        \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,C)
        \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,B)
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](A,C,B)
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](C,B,A)
        \tkzDrawPoints[fill=gray](A,B,C,D,E,F,G)
         \tkzDrawSegment[dashed](C,F)
     \end{tikzpicture}
    \hspace{0.3cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
       \Tri{B}{3}{0}{C}{1.5}{3}{A}{none}
       \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=2](A,B)           \tkzGetPoint{E}
    \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=2](A,C)      \tkzGetPoint{D}
        \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=1.5](A,B)            \tkzGetPoint{F}
        \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=1.5](A,C)            \tkzGetPoint{G} 
        \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
        \tkzDrawSegment(A,E)
        \tkzDrawSegment(A,D)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left](E)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right](D)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left](F)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right](G)       
        \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,C)
        \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,B)
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](A,C,B)
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](C,B,A)
        \tkzDrawSegment[dashed](B,G)
        \tkzDrawPoints[fill=gray](A,B,C,D,E,F,G)
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \hspace{0.3cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
       \Tri{B}{3}{0}{C}{1.5}{3}{A}{none}
          \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=2](A,B)            \tkzGetPoint{E}
        \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=2](A,C)          \tkzGetPoint{D}
        \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=1.5](A,B)            \tkzGetPoint{F}
        \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=1.5](A,C)            \tkzGetPoint{G} 
        \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
        \tkzDrawSegment(A,E)
        \tkzDrawSegment(A,D)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left](E)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right](D)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left](F)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right](G)       
        \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,C)
        \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,B)
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](A,C,B)
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](C,B,A)
        \tkzDrawSegment[dashed](B,G)
          \tkzDrawSegment[dashed](C,F)
        \tkzDrawPoints[fill=gray](A,B,C,D,E,F,G)
    \end{diagram}


    \section{aaaaaa}
    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx
    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx
    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx
    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx
    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx
    \section{aaaaaa}
    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx
    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx
    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx
    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx
    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx
    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx
    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx
    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx
    \section{aaaaaa}
    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx
    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx
    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx
    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx
    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx    xxxx xxxx
    \end{document}
```

which produces

```
Underfull \vbox (badness 4108) has occurred while \output is active
```

As `book` class defaults to `\flushbottom` but you can not have a page break immediately after the section heading, the whole of section 0.3 has to go to the next page, then there is not enough flexible glue or text to reach the bottom of page 1 without over-stretching the white space, hence the warning.

You could write more text, to fill the space, or add `\vfill` after the diagram to allow more white space, or use `\clearpage` before section 3 to force a short page.